# What is the openssl version used by aws_sdk for c++?

Tags: amazon-web-services, openssl, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

What is the openssl version used by aws_sdk for c++? And how can we make SDK to support particular version of openssl?

Answer (score 0):

Currently the SDK targets 1.0.x. We need to update the SDK to handle 1.1.x and later. There is currently a [pull request](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-cpp/pull/362) request for this. We'll evaluate it and get it merged in as soon as possible.